# Warrants and travel

Tags: airports

If a Canadian has a warrant for failing to appear (in Canada), however, was already in Europe at the time it was issued... can he  travel out of the Schengen zone to a non Schengen country ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are not out to help criminals on the lam.

Comment: @chx, we can't help him anyway. If the case is serious enough, Canada may ask the Schengen nation to arrest him *where he is now*, regardless of any border crossings. The best option is to turn himself in and clear things up the legal way.

Answer (score 5):

Canada may or may not have issued an [Interpol notice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpol_notice). If so, the border officials may or may not be aware of the fact, and they may or may not act on the interpol notice. Impossible to tell.

For something minor like a traffic fine, an extradition request will be unlikely. For something major, allied countries tend to help each other.